# Reference - Moment approximation error vs. L2 error

Tags: references, moments, approximation

The following is a standard, but I couldn't find a single textbook for it. **Could you help me find a reference for this lemma?**

Given $f,f_N \in L^2 (\Omega) \cap L^1 (\Omega)$ for some probability space $(\Omega , \mu )$, then
$$\left| \mathbb{E}_{\alpha} [f] - \mathbb{E}_{\alpha} [f_N] \right| \leq \|f - f_N\|_2 \, ,$$
$$
\left| {\rm Var}(f) - {\rm  Var}(f_N) \right| \leq \|f-f_N\|_2 \cdot (\|f\|_2 +\|f_N\|_2 ) \, ,
$$
$$
|\sigma(f)-\sigma(f_N) | \leq \frac{\|f\|_2 + \|f_N\|_2}{\sigma(f) +\sigma(f_N)} \|f-f_N\|_2 \, .
$$

In other words, the $L^2$ error bounds the moment approximation error.

*Note-* This is somewhat overlapping with [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/285128/42864) MathOverflow post.
Thanks